# How do I check an array for two specific characters at the start in several different numbers in the array?

Tags: python, arrays

My goal is to make it so that a person inputs 5 codes that start with either "SB" or "SC" with 3 numbers on the end of it.
Currently i have :

```
  mylist = []

  x = [str(i) for i in input().split()]

  mylist.extend(x)
```

How do I make the program check that the first two letters are either SB or SC and to check that the last 3 are numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if a string matches a pattern can be done with a regular expression, use the `re` module.

### Code

```
import re

inputs = [str(i) for i in input('> ').split()]

if len(inputs) == 5 and all(re.fullmatch(r'S(B|C)\d{3}', i) for i in inputs):
    print(inputs)
else:
    print('Incorrect format')
```

### Examples

Correct format...

```
> SC123 SC234 SB456 SC543 SB543
['SC123', 'SC234', 'SB456', 'SC543', 'SB543']
```

Incorrect format...

```
> SC123 SC234 SB456 SC543 SA234
Incorrect format
```